# Why does Uber have no Google Maps copyright attribution?

Tags: copyright

On Uber's Google Map, there is no line with attribution to Google's data providers.

But the Google guidelines say very clearly:

> All uses of Google Maps ... **must provide attribution to both Google and our data providers**. We do not approve of any use of content without proper attribution, in any circumstance. ... **Requests for exceptions will not be answered or granted.** ... Only including “Google” or the Google logo is not proper attribution when there are third-party data providers cited with the imagery. (https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html)

Why does Uber not attribute the copyright properly? Is this even legal?

Answer (score 8):

If that is the licence that Uber are operating under then they are breaking it. This is not legal in that Google can sue them for copyright breach.

However, this is the licence that Google offer to the average person on the street for which they pay Google nothing. It is entirely possible that Uber and Google have come to terms on a completely different licence arrangement which may involve Uber handing over slabs of cash (or not) and not needing to attribute.

Google is free to offer licences on different terms to different people.

Comment: Considering Google has invested [at least a quarter of a billion dollars in Uber](https://techcrunch.com/2013/08/22/google-ventures-puts-258m-into-uber-its-largest-deal-ever/) I think it's possible they might also let Uber use their map service without attribution.